# Socket Hang Up when using https.request in node.js

Tags: ssl, node.js

When using https.request with node.js v04.7, I get the following error:

```
Error: socket hang up
    at CleartextStream.<anonymous> (http.js:1272:45)
    at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:61:17)
    at Array.<anonymous> (tls.js:617:22)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

Simplified code that will generate the error:

```
var https = require('https')
  , fs    = require('fs')

var options = {
  host: 'localhost'
, port: 8000
, key: fs.readFileSync('../../test-key.pem')
, cert: fs.readFileSync('../../test-cert.pem')
}

// Set up server and start listening
https.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
  res.end('success')
}).listen(options.port, options.host)

// Wait a second to let the server start up
setTimeout(function() {
  var clientRequest = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log('Called')
    })
  })

  clientRequest.write('')
  clientRequest.end()
}, 1000)
```

I get the error even with the server and client running on different node instances and have tested with port 8000, 3000, and 443 and with and without the SSL certificates. I do have libssl and libssl-dev on my Ubuntu machine.

Any ideas on what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

`https.createServer(function (req, res) {`

you are missing options when you create the server, should be:

`https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {`

with your key and cert inside

Comment: Wow, thanks @Quentin. So simple. I had the options hash defined, but forgot to pass it to createServer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem where the response's end event never fired.

Adding this line fixed the problem:

```
// Hack to emit end on close because of a core bug that never fires end
response.on('close', function () {response.emit('end')});
```

I found an example of this in the request library mentioned in the previous answer.

Comment: Thanks, but adding the close event handler didn't work. I tried adding it on this line: https://github.com/baalexander/node-xmlrpc/blob/master/lib/client.js#L63

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** [Use the the latest source code](https://github.com/mikeal/request/raw/master/main.js) instead of the one you have. Store it where you will and then require it, you are good to go.

---

In the request 1.2.0 source code, main.js line 76, I see

```
http.createClient(options.uri.port, options.uri.hostname, options.uri.protocol === 'https:');
```

Looking at [the http.js source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/205b9beb6be0d563a85027158e8af3bee8472b9e/lib/http.js#L1581), I see

```
exports.createClient = function(port, host) {
  var c = new Client();
  c.port = port;
  c.host = host;
  return c;
};
```

It is requesting with 3 params but the actual function only has 2. The functionality is replaced with a separate module for https.

Looking at [the latest main.js source code](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/master/main.js), I see dramatic changes. The most important is [the addition of `require('https')`](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/8bb7f98ba8b78c217552c979811c07f1299318fe/main.js#L25).

It appears that request has been fixed but never re-released. Fortunately, the fix seems to work if you just copy manually from [the raw view of the latest main.js source code](https://github.com/mikeal/request/raw/master/main.js) and use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i think i got a fix.  but then I have another socket problem.
See my solution here: http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/9189df2597aa199e/b83b16c08a051706?lnk=gst&q=hang+up#b83b16c08a051706

key point: use 0.4.8,  http.request instead of http.createClient.

However, the new problem is, if I let the program running for long time, (I actually left the program running but no activity during weekend), then I will get socket hang up error when I send a request to http Server. (not even reach the http.request).  I don't know if it is because of my code, or it is different problem with http Server